# Using new operator for copy an object to heap without knowing its type

Tags: c++, inheritance, new-operator

I have a doubt, the function below can receive an object of type A or something derived type.

```
A *copyToHeap(A &obj) {
    A *ptr=new A(obj);
    return ptr;
}
```

If we call it like this:

```
//B inherits from A
B bObj;
B *hPtr=copyToHeap(bObj);
```

The object pointed by `hPtr` is actually of type A or B?
Is safe doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you do the below in your code:

```
A* ptr = new A(obj);
```

you'll always get an A instance.  obj will be treated as an A and a new A will get created based on the "A part" of obj.

The better approach is as an earlier reply indicated, add a virtual MakeCopy method to the base class and implement it for the derived classes.

```
virtual A* MakeCopy();
```

This method is implemented by making a copy of the object for which its called.  It then gets implemented in the derived classes so if you have an A pointer which is actually a B object you'll get a true B copy and avoid the "slicing" which is occurring in your example.

Answer (score 5):

The returned object is of type `pointer to A`, which means the object pointed to by `hPtr` is of type `A`. It's not safe since calling methods or members exclusive to B will cause a crash or undefined behavior. You're probably looking for the [factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html).

Answer (score 3):

A safe way is to provide a virtual clone method

```
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> Clone() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int i) : i_(i)
    {

    }

    std::unique_ptr<Base> Clone()
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived(i_));
    }

private:
    int i_;
};


std::unique_ptr<Base> copyToHeap(std::unique_ptr<Base> obj) 
{
    return obj->Clone();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe, it is incorrect, and the compiler should give you some diagnostics. Did you try to compile with `g++ -Wall` if using GCC?

Comment: Sorry, I written the code from memory and I could not try to comile.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't compile:

```
B *hPtr=copyToHeap(bObj); //error: invalid conversion from ‘A*’ to ‘B*’
```

If you change the type of `hPtr` to `A*` it compiles, but you still get an `A` object. The default copy-constructor for `A` which you use will create an `A` object and copy the fields of the `B` object which were defined in `A`, slicing the `B` part off.

Answer (score 0):

Because of all the problems described above/in this post -- if at all you can avoid it (and I can't think of a reason why you couldn't) -- you should not design your code to require "`copyToHeap`".

As Luchian points out, you probably want a factory. The factory creates your object on the heap to begin with (and returns a smart pointer to manage the lifetime of the object/pointer/memory).